# Python: Why does my 'less than' test fail?

Tags: python

I have the following program:

```
def eigen(a, b, c, d, e, f):
    epsilon = 1E-9
    a = abs(float(a*e+b*f)/float(c*e+d*f) - float(e)/float(f))
    print a, epsilon
    print a < epsilon
    print abs((a*e+b*f)/float(c*e+d*f) - e/float(f)) < epsilon
```

Prints:

```
0.0 1e-09
True
False
```

when the values of `a,b,c,...,f = 3, 1, 1, 3, 4, -4`

I expected the last two lines to both print `True` as I thought they were equivelent statements. Will you kindly explain to me what is going on?

Thank you for your time.

Kind regards,

Marius

Comment: If you wanted these to be equivalent, why did you write one with extra `float(…)` conversions, but not the other? (That isn't causing your problem here, but still, it's a sign that you're not being very careful…)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that

```
a = abs(float(a*e+b*f)/float(c*e+d*f) - float(e)/float(f))
```

assigns a different value to `a`, which messes up the calculation that follows:

```
print abs((a*e+b*f)/float(c*e+d*f) - e/float(f)) < epsilon
#          ^ This is no longer the original a
```

Comment: haha. nice catch. didn't see it at first

Comment: @Claudiu: Yeah, took me some staring at the code to spot it. :)